# soundcloud ruby gem, how to resolve user id (or track url) to user resource

Tags: ruby, api, sdk, rubygems, soundcloud

does it exist in the soundcloud gem the function to resolve from a user_id (or track url) to user resource so that i have access to the properties of the user resource, similar to the 'resolve track URL into track resource' example

track = client.get('/resolve', :url => track_url)

Answer (score 0):

The track variable in your example should result in a redirect to the API resource representative of the track and thereby contain a user_id property you can access. Then you can resolve into a user resource by invoking the client with the /users method.

```
track = client.get('/resolve', :url => some_url)
puts track.user_id
user = client.get('/users', :id => track.user_id)
puts user
```